# Android Studio error when i try to change my theme's app by code

Tags: android

I made an XML file that contains a switchCompat View. Throught that i want to switch from light to dark theme. In my java code i made a method to make the switch work, but when i click on the switch view the app crashes.

Error:

```
"2022-06-09 16:55:24.942 19311-19311/com.example.dailyart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dailyart, PID: 19311
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1931)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1967)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:726)
    at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:657)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:284)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:302)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:3215)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroy(FragmentStateManager.java:774)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:350)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete(SpecialEffectsController.java:745)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.completeSpecialEffect(SpecialEffectsController.java:672)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController$SpecialEffectsInfo.completeSpecialEffect(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:776)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.startAnimations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:147)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.executeOperations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:120)
    at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.executePendingOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:297)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2202)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8076)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:61)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
```

When i open the fragment containing switch method for changing the theme of my app

```
SwitchCompat switchCompat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Dark);
    }
    else{
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Light);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_settings);

    TextView logout = findViewById(R.id.tvLogout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(view -> logout());

    switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    
    switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add more code (about fragment transactions) in question?

Comment: same instance of FragmentManager is used in different fragment transactions which is throwing this error you need to create separate instance for another transaction

Comment: I don't undestand what you mean by "different fragment transactions". Could you explain what is happening to my fragment when i try to swicth the theme?